# show command details with at

Tags: at

I am very new to using at and am wondering how to display the command by a scheduled job.

```
postgres@dcjsn-jv2526:/opt/db/backup/postgres/dumps> atq
29      Wed Nov  2 18:55:00 2022 a postgres
```

I see there is a job 29 scheduled for a certain time by a certain user. Now I want to examine the command to be executed. How do I achieve that? There is nothing on this in the manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
at -c 29
```

should do it. Note that the job file includes your full environment, so scroll down to the bottom if necessary to see the script that is executed.

The `at(1)` man page says:

```
       -c     cats the jobs listed on the command line to standard output.
```

You need to be superuser to examine jobs of other users though.

Comment: thks. I even read it, but just did not recognize it for what is does.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done in this way

```bash
┌──[root@vms83.liruilongs.github.io]-[/var/spool/at]
└─$ls /var/spool/at/
a0000101a80dd0  a0000201a80dd0  spool
┌──[root@vms83.liruilongs.github.io]-[/var/spool/at]
└─$cat a0000201a80dd0
```

Comment: How would you connect the cryptic filename with a particular `at` job?

Comment: `a0000{job_id}01a80dd0 ` It looks like this

Comment: You need to be superuser to do the `ls` of `/var/spool/at` I believe. OTOH, `at -c 29` will work as long as you are the owner of the job. I also tried to `cat` the file directly and I still get `permission denied` even though I own it: the directory perms don't allow it. So even if you can guess the filename, you won't be able to see it unless you are the superuser.